# Mouse support in QWS

Tags: qt4, embedded, mouse

I have compiled Qt4 embedded SDK for using on BeagleBoard with following options:

```
./configure 
-embedded arm 
-platform qws/linux-x86-g++ 
-xplatform qws/linux-TIarmv7-sgx-g++ 
-depths 16,24,32 
-no-mmx 
-no-3dnow 
-no-sse 
-no-sse2 
-no-glib 
-no-cups 
-no-largefile 
-no-accessibility 
-no-openssl 
-no-gtkstyle 
-qt-mouse-pc 
-qt-mouse-linuxtp 
-qt-mouse-linuxinput 
-plugin-mouse-linuxtp 
-plugin-mouse-pc 
-fast -opengl es2 
-qt-gfx-transformed 
-qt-gfx-vnc 
-qt-gfx-linuxfb 
-qt-gfx-multiscreen 
-plugin-gfx-powervr 
-D QT_QWS_CLIENTBLIT 
-opensource 
-confirm-license 
-multimedia 
-optimized-qmake
```

Than I have created a simple Hello World GUI application with this SDK and compiled successfully. And I have run my application on BeagleBoard:

```
./Hello World -mouse -qws
```

But my mouse did not work. Then I tried setting  **QWS_MOUSE_PROTO** to **Microsoft**, **IntelliMouse** and **MouseMan** as mentioned in Qt4 docs before running my application but it did not work. I have tested my mouse before running my application so I am sure my mouse works. I am using Angstrom on my Beagleboard.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=IntelliMouse:/dev/input/mice`?

What input driver are you using? `evdev` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

export QWS_KEYBOARD="LinuxInput:/dev/input/event0 LinuxInput:/dev/input/event1"
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO="LinuxInput:/dev/input/event0 LinuxInput:/dev/input/event1"